# Data is not deleted from mysql. Is there any other way to do the same?

Tags: python, pymysql

I am trying to delete some record from mysql database using pymysql but i couldn't able to do.The same command if i execute in mysql its working.

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Connect to the MYSQL database
logger.info("Connecting to MySQL database")
try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, database=db_name, cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur = conn.cursor()
except:
    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySql instance.")
    sys.exit()

logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to MySQL database succeeded")

def _clean_general_logs():
    cur.execute(
        "DELETE FROM desker.general_log WHERE event_time <= '2019-08-12 04:36:42.457536' ORDER BY event_time DESC limit 10")
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return {"result": True}
```

Comment: What are `last_event_timestamp` and `last_event_time`?

Comment: Can you specify what the output of the command is? What error are you encountering?

Comment: You dont need to declare `result` because delete statement doesn’t return like select statement. Just `cur.execute(.........)`.

Comment: Where is `cur` defined?

Comment: hii jaypeerachai, yeah you are right but delete statements returns how many rows are affected so i print result to check wheather  is it affected the table or not.

Comment: hii Peter Wood, the code has been updated please have a look on the code.

Comment: You define the function `_clean_general_logs` but you don't actually invoke it.